# What are some strategies for using CSS classes to library HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am developing a library of HTML components.  The underlying technology is not relevant;  the code for each component just generates HTML that is ultimately sent to the browser.

The problem I'm having is that a lot of the generated HTML needs to be styled by the application.  And I don't know ahead of time exactly what that styling might be.  Also, the generated HTML tends to have several divs and spans for, each of which might be styled differently.  Think of something like a calendar component and all the different ways that might be styled.

At first I thought I'd just assign a class to every non-trivial element.  I prefixed all my class names with "foo" (the name of my library), so the div for the calendar component has class foo-calendar.  But inside the components I started to wonder about this approach because I kept having to make up weird names for all the various divs that make up each one.  And what about when there's only one tag of a certain type in the component?  Do I still give it a class even though it doesn't add any additional meaning?

The I started thinking that I'll only add enough classes to uniquely identify each tag.  So if there's only one input field in the component, I won't give it a class at all, because the CSS selector ".foo-calendar input" will find it.  But this approach seems a little too subjective.

Another question I have is, do I prefix all my class names with the name of my library, or only the "top-level" classes?  Or do I nest the class names?  In other words if the calendar has class foo-calendar, then does the month display have the class "month" or "foo-month" or "foo-calendar-month?"

What strategies do you follow for assigning CSS classes to library HTML?

Comment: Who's going to be styling them?  I think the norm is for you to create the CSS and HTML, thus giving you control and knowledge of where classes are needed, and when they're not.

Comment: Have you done a google search for 'Object Oriented CSS'?

Comment: If I was generating the CSS then everything would be fine: I'd just add as many classes as necessary to do the styling that I need.  But I'm writing components that other developers will use in as-yet-undefined web applications.  Of course designing things for unknown requirements is a good way waste lots of time.  So what I'm trying to do is come up with a strategy that I can follow that will enable these other developers to style their app according to their requirements in most cases, without my having to invest a lot of time right now.

Comment: "OOCSS:"  Nope, but I'll do it now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say more classes is better (to make css selection easier), and namespace them all (to avoid collision), but I'm imagining a WordPress plugin or something modular that I might want to plug into my existing website.

I really like the way Gravity Forms structured their html classes, because it makes it easy for me to tweak and customize without having to touch the markup, so if that's what you're looking for, maybe take a look at their CSS Guide: http://www.gravityhelp.com/gravity-forms-css-visual-guide/

Answer (score 0):

If you add a reset declaration you don't need to prefix all your classnames. You'll find a proper reset-css in several css frameworks.

I would use as less as possible classes for your elements (and would use no IDs), as you have described in the 4th paragraph.

Of course if you do this, your css selectors are becoming very long - but maybe you could use SASS/SCSS to prevent totally chaos ;-)

Comment: I can't require a reset.css because I'm not writing an application, only a library.  I have to assume that the app will have its own divs, spans, inputs, etc. and its own classes that are not part of the library.

Comment: Okay, but will the app add code inside of your library elements? Will they write stuff in the <div class="fooCalendar" /> element? If not you could add a second class which assigns the reset definitions just for this single "widget" and its contents.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into OOCSS (Object Oriented CSS).

Code - https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss

Introduction - http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/23/object-oriented-css-video-on-ydn/

I personally like this method because it feels easier to style elements on the page.

The basic idea to evaluate the styles you have on your page then create some general purpose classes that can be applied throughout your site. Sometimes I get very granular and I create a class like `.bold {font-weight:bold}` but most of the time this should not be done. Also another key idea is to separate CSS structure (your grids, positioning, etc.) and your styles (colors, font-weight, backgrounds, etc.). This is done to improve maintainability.

If you find a common theme in how your widgets are styled then break that out into a class and apply as needed. For example, all over the web there are elements that have an image to the left and text on the right. See your SO signature at the bottom of your question here. This could be made into a generic class that could be applied any instance of a widget with an image to the left and text on the right.